# Read the file while python is still rewriting the file

Tags: python, file-writing

I am trying to access the content of a file while that file is still being updated. Following is my code that does the writing to file job:

```
for i in range(100000):
    fp = open("text.txt", "w")
    fp.write(str(i))
    fp.close()
    #time.sleep(1)
```

My problem now is that whenever I try to open my file while the for loop is still running, I get an empty file in text editor(I except to see an "updated" number). 
I am wondering is there a way that allows me to view the content of file before the for loop ends?

Thanks in advance for any help: )

Comment: What do you expect to see?

Comment: I expect to see a updated number every time when I open the file.

Comment: when you do `fp=open("text.txt",'w')` you roll back to the beginning of the file, remove everything. It will stay like that until "commit" writing such as `fp.flush()`. This is the major portion of your activity during the loop. When you open the file, very likely you are in such a period and you will see nothing. You can change your `time.sleep(n)` to a very small number and you will see nothing too.

Comment: Again what do you try to accomplish here? Communication between different processes?

Answer (score 4):

**Do not** open file inside for loop. It is a bad practice and bad code.
   Each and every time you create a new object. That is why you get an empty file.

```
fp = open("text.txt", "r+")
for i in range(100000):
    fp.seek(0)
    fp.write(str(i))
    fp.truncate()
fp.close()
```

Comment: I'm actually trying to update the file with a new number. If I should not try to use file-open in for loop, what else can I do?

Comment: you cannot erase a file unless you need to erase the end.Either be content with an overwrite of an "empty" value,

Comment: I don't quite understand, could you please give me an example? thank you

Comment: feel free to upvote and accept my answer. It will be useful for others

Answer (score 2):

Modern operating systems buffer file writes to improve performance: several consecutive writes are lumped together before they are actually written to the disc. If you want the writes to propagate to the disk immediately, use method `flush()`, but remember that it *drastically* reduces application performance:

```
with open("text.txt", "w") as fp:
  for i in range(100000):
    fp.write(str(i))
    fp.flush()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write to a file it usually does not actually get written to disk until file is closed. If you want it to be written immediately you need to add a `flush` to each iteration, hence:

```
fp = open("text.txt", "w")
for i in range(100000):
    fp.write(str(i))
    fp.write("\n")
    fp.flush()
fp.close()
```

Comment: I'm actually trying to update the file with the i number, I found that if I add sleep at the end of the for-loop, it works fine when I open the file(with an updated number), however is there a way without time sleeping?

Comment: flush() is faster, when you use sleep it flushes but you're wasting time sleeping.